# Use Vuex classic mode in Nuxt application

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I'm rewriting Vue application to Nuxt architecture because we want SSR. However I don't want to rewrite Vuex store file which is:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import vuexI18n from "vuex-i18n/dist/vuex-i18n.umd.js";
import toEnglish from "../translations/toEnglish";
import toSpanish from "./../translations/toSpanish";
import toGerman from "./../translations/toGerman";
import toRussian from "./../translations/toRussian";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        currentLanguage: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        changeLang: (state, response) => {
            if(response) {
                state.currentLanguage = response;
                Vue.i18n.set(response);
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
    }
});

Vue.use(vuexI18n.plugin, store);
Vue.i18n.add("en", toEnglish);
Vue.i18n.add("es", toSpanish);
Vue.i18n.add("de", toGerman);
Vue.i18n.add("ru", toRussian);

export default store;
```

I know that Nuxt has some other approach to that but I really want to stick with above code. Unfortuenally I can't call mutation from my component by:

```
this.$store.commit('changeLang', lang)
```

it print error in console:

> [vuex] unknown mutation type: changeLang

I also tried like this

```
this.$store.commit('store/changeLang', lang)
```

but error is same. How to fix it? Do I need to rewrite this vuex file in order to make it work?

---

I followed @Aldarund tips and changed above code to:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import vuexI18n from "vuex-i18n/dist/vuex-i18n.umd.js";
import toEnglish from "../translations/toEnglish";
import toSpanish from "./../translations/toSpanish";
import toGerman from "./../translations/toGerman";
import toRussian from "./../translations/toRussian";

const store = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: () => ({
            currentLanguage: ''
        }),
        mutations: {
            changeLang: (state, response) => {
                if (response) {
                    state.currentLanguage = response;
                    Vue.i18n.set(response);
                    console.log(response);
                }
            }
        }
    })
};

Vue.use(vuexI18n.plugin, store);
Vue.i18n.add("en", toEnglish);
Vue.i18n.add("es", toSpanish);
Vue.i18n.add("de", toGerman);
Vue.i18n.add("ru", toRussian);

export default store;
```

now error is

> Uncaught TypeError: store.registerModule is not a function

It's probably because of `Vue.use(vuexI18n.plugin, store);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use classic mode.

> Classic (deprecated): store/index.js returns a method to create a
>   store instance

So it should look like this, no vuex use, on import of Vue. And it must be a function that crestr store, not plain vuex object

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: () => ({
      counter: 0
    }),
    mutations: {
      increment (state) {
        state.counter++
      }
    }
  })
}

export default createStore
```

Docs https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#classic-mode

As for plugin e.g. vyexi18 you need to move that code into plugin file and get created store object from context https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/

```
export default ({ store }) => {
  Your vuex18initcode
}
```

Comment: Well but if I move i18n to plugin directory I will not be able to call Vue.i18n.set(response); from my changeLang mutation.

Comment: @BT101 change Vue to this

Comment: `this.i18n.set(response);` cause error `Cannot read property 'i18n' of undefined` :( `this` is undefined inside mutation.

Comment: @BT101 it's because arrow functions. Define action like in my answer example

Comment: I still can't access i18n from mutation. I'll separate it to other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565138/not-able-to-access-i18-plugin-from-mutation-in-classic-mode-store-in-nuxt-applic