# Not able to access i18 plugin from mutation in classic mode store in Nuxt application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, internationalization, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to implement Vuex i18n package within my Nuxt application. In my nuxt.conf.js file in plugins array I have:

```
{
    src: '@/plugins/i18n.js',
    ssr: false
},
```

plugins/i18n.js file is:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import vuexI18n from "vuex-i18n/dist/vuex-i18n.umd.js";
import toEnglish from "../translations/toEnglish";
import toSpanish from "./../translations/toSpanish";
import toGerman from "./../translations/toGerman";

export default ({ store }) => {
    Vue.use(
        vuexI18n.plugin,
        store,
        {
            onTranslationNotFound: function (locale, key) {
                console.warn(`vuex-i18n :: Key '${key}' not found for locale '${locale}'`)
            }
        }
    );

    // register the locales
    Vue.i18n.add('en', toEnglish);
    Vue.i18n.add('de', toGerman);
    Vue.i18n.add('es', toSpanish);

    // Set the start locale to use
    Vue.i18n.set('de');
    Vue.i18n.fallback('en');
}
```

Last thing is my store. I'm using classic mode of vuex store in Nuxt:

```
import Vuex from "vuex";

const store = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: () => ({
            currentLanguage: ''
        }),
        mutations: {
            changeLang(state, response) {
                if (response) {
                    console.log(this);
                    state.currentLanguage = response;
                    this.i18n.set(response);
                }
            }
        }
    })
};


export default store;
```

As you can see in store file in mutation I'm trying to access i18n plugin with `this` keyword. Unfortunetally in print error in console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

`this` which I consoled also inside mutation is:

[image: Not able to access i18 plugin from mutation in classic mode store in nuxt application]

Comment: Check this.app object

Comment: There is nothing related to i18n inside `this.app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `this.i18n.set(response);` to `state.i18n.locale = response;` inside my mutation and now it seems working.

For some reason when I call this mutation my video.js player refresh. I will try to find out why.